# stored procedure to call a specific column using parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Hi this is the code i used in mysql and its working fine ..Is there any way to declare a variable for GRP and call it in the code. so that i could use the code again if i have to do math on some other column other than grp  and any other name  ,since the names keep changing all the time

```
     SELECT GRP,
     @_11:=power(GRP,0.1)+0.1*@_11 AS GRP_11 ,
     @_12:=power(GRP,0.2)+0.1*@_12 AS GRP_12 ,
     @_13:=power(GRP,0.3)+0.1*@_13 AS GRP_13 ,
     @_14:=power(GRP,0.4)+0.1*@_14 AS GRP_14 ,
     @_15:=power(GRP,0.5)+0.1*@_15 AS GRP_15 ,
     @_16:=power(GRP,0.6)+0.1*@_16 AS GRP_16 ,
     @_17:=power(GRP,0.7)+0.1*@_17 AS San_Orange_CS_GRP_17 ,
     @_18:=power(GRP,0.8)+0.1*@_18 AS GRP_18 ,
     @_19:=power(GRP,0.9)+0.1*@_19 AS GRP_19 ,
     from DUMMY JOIN (SELECT @_11:=0,@_12:=0,@_13:=0,@_14:=0,@_15:=0,@_16:=0,
     @_17:=0,@_18:=0,@_19:=0) t;
```

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: You can use like `select @grp:=GRP as grp, @_11:=power( @grp,0.1)+0.1*@_11 AS GRP_11, ...`

Comment: @Ravinder What about the  AS GRP_11 ?  is it possible to change GRP there too ?

Comment: meaning? can you show some example?

Comment: @_11:=power(@grp,0.1)+0.1*@_11 AS concat "@grp" , "_11"

Comment: Value would be changing for every row where as col names are evaluated only once per table. Hence won't work unless the resulting table has single row result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline variable.

**Example**:

```
select @grp:=GRP as grp, @_11:=power( @grp,0.1)+0.1*@_11 AS GRP_11, ...
```

Change your query as below:

```
SELECT 
     @grp := GRP as grp,
     @_11 := power( @grp, 0.1 ) + 0.1 * @_11 AS GRP_11 ,
     @_12 := power( @grp, 0.2 ) + 0.1 * @_12 AS GRP_12 ,
     @_13 := power( @grp, 0.3 ) + 0.1 * @_13 AS GRP_13 ,
     @_14 := power( @grp, 0.4 ) + 0.1 * @_14 AS GRP_14 ,
     @_15 := power( @grp, 0.5 ) + 0.1 * @_15 AS GRP_15 ,
     @_16 := power( @grp, 0.6 ) + 0.1 * @_16 AS GRP_16 ,
     @_17 := power( @grp, 0.7 ) + 0.1 * @_17 AS San_Orange_CS_GRP_17 ,
     @_18 := power( @grp, 0.8 ) + 0.1 * @_18 AS GRP_18 ,
     @_19 := power( @grp, 0.9 ) + 0.1 * @_19 AS GRP_19 ,
FROM DUMMY
     JOIN ( 
            SELECT @_11:=0, @_12:=0, @_13:=0, @_14:=0, @_15:=0, 
                   @_16:=0, @_17:=0, @_18:=0, @_19:=0 
          ) t;
```

Comment: Is it possible to give...........   AS @grp_11,  Since i have to change the name often...

Comment: This is possible only with a prepared statement in a stored procedure.

Comment: But it would be meaningful if the query returns a single row. For a multi row result set, we can't set alias for each of the row and it would be an error too.

Comment: I suggest you to post some sample data with their column names and your expected result table with their modified column/expression names. Someone from SO will help you.